# How to analyze a df with multiple bits of info in each entry?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Lets say we have the following df:

```
Premier League Team  Manchester United     Everton ....
Aston Villa               2-0                3-0
Arsenal                   2-1                1-3
```

Each entry in the row represents a score of a game (i.e. Aston Villa won 2-0 against Manchester United). How would you extract the scores to see total # of wins? (for example: how many wins aston villa had throughout the season?)

EDIT:
The columns represent all the games in the soccer season that they played (In this case, they will play all the teams in the premier league once).

Result DF considering the first two results for each team:

```
Premier League Team    # of Wins
Aston Villa               2
Arsenal                   1
```

Comment: What's a "season"?

Comment: Like a soccer season (i.e. like from august to may). The columns represent the games they played in that single season.

Comment: Will you please show a dataframe containing your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `eval`

```
out = df.set_index('Premier League Team').applymap(eval).ge(0).sum(1)
```

Comment: Sweet! Any idea how to do this in R?

Comment: Please ask that in a new question, @Dylan.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that using `eval` is considered very insecure. Only use it if in you _know_ that the values it will be used with are safe. You know, if your one of the columns had arbitrary Python code (such as `os.system("sudo rm -rf /")`), you could be in big trouble! :D